# PHP for each Loop return only certain elements

Tags: php, foreach, pagination

I am using an API from Bittrex , reading the json and then looping through with a for each loop to get the info i need

everything is working correctly.  and here is the code :

```
     foreach($return[result] as $x=>$x_value){
            extract($x_value);
            echo $OrderUuid." " .$closedDate ."  " .$closedTime ."    " .$Quantity."  " .$Price."  " . $PricePerUnit * 100000000 ." <br>";
       }
```

But, What I want to do because I am putting this into a table with pagination is I need to be able to only  echo out results like 1-5  then next page will be 6-11 and so on

i know the count already  by using this and it returns the amount of results.

```
$thisManyResults=count($return[result]);
```

I know i need to keep in mind that index starts at ZERO as well.

Loops  confuse me so badly, please also give an explanation for a newbie to wrap his head around. Thank you

EDIT:

```
foreach($return[result] as $x=>$x_value){
    extract($x_value);


    $str66 = str_replace('T', ' ', $TimeStamp);
    $newarray = explode(" ", $str66);
    $date =date_create($newarray[0]);
    $closedDate = date_format($date,"m/d/Y");
    $closedTime = date("g:i:s a", strtotime($newarray[1]));


    // echo $OrderUuid."      " .$closedDate ."           " .$closedTime ."    " .$Quantity."      " .$Price."      " . $PricePerUnit * 100000000 ." <br>";


        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'>". $Quantity ." </td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $Price." </center></td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $PricePerUnit * 100000000 ." </center></td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $closedDate." </center></td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $closedTime." </center></td></tr>";

  }
```

but this shows ALL results  0-22 (23 results)   I need to be able to only show in table   0 thru 5   or 6 thru 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the final code in case someone else can be helped

```
$start="0";
$end ="8";
foreach (array_slice($return[result], $start ,$end )  as $x=>$x_value) {
    extract($x_value);

    $str66 = str_replace('T', ' ', $TimeStamp);
    $newarray = explode(" ", $str66);
    $date =date_create($newarray[0]);
    $closedDate = date_format($date,"m/d/Y");
    $closedTime = date("g:i:s a", strtotime($newarray[1]));

        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'>". $Quantity ." </td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $Price." </center></td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $PricePerUnit * 100000000 ." </center></td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $closedDate." </center></td>";
        echo "<td style='text-decoration:none;color:#000000;font-weight:normal'><center>". $closedTime." </center></td></tr>";

    }

}
```

I got this info by looking at @gabriele's answer where he posted about `array_slice`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can Help you

```
// Array example 
$array=[
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
$_GET["page"] = 1; // This is variable that you have to pass 
$pagination = 4; // Number of items 4 = 5, 5 = 6
if( !isset($_GET["page"]) ){ 
    // If $_GET is not null, starting page from 0 to 4 ( total 5 items )
    $start = 0;
    $end = $pagination;
}else{
    //else, calculate variable pagination * number page
    $start += $pagination * ( $_GET["page"] - 1 );
    //increments end variable
    $end +=  $start + $pagination;
}
// Range from array
$range=[$start,$end];
$a=array_keys(array_intersect(array_keys($array),$range));
// slice the desired elements using offset and calculated length
foreach(  array_slice($array,$a[0],$a[1]-$a[0]+1) as $v){
    // Printing results 
    echo $v . " ";
}
```

Comment: i actually have the pagination worked out.   I just need to be able to only display(echo)  from result  #5  thru  #10  ...  the api does NOT have a start and end so i have to call it each time.

Comment: im trying to add  array slice now to the updated code above

Comment: my code is just an example, you don't need to have start and end from API if you have all results already stored in array